# Как при помощи метода изменить шрифт у всех activity

Tags: java, android, textview, typeface

```
String fontPath ="fonts/smartoff.net_verdana.ttf";
    int[] array_id_font=new int[]{R.id.umivanie_text,R.id.eda_text,R.id.son_text};
 Typeface verdana;
```

Хочу при помощи метода менять шрифт во всех активностях.
Делаю так:

```
 public void setFont()
    {
          verdana = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
       for (int i=0;i<array_id_font.length;i++){
           array_id_font[i]///как применить
что тут добавить?///.setTypeface(verdana)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

создать базовый класс для активити

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected String fontPath ="fonts/smartoff.net_verdana.ttf";
private Typeface typeface;

protected int[] getTextViewsResIds() {
    return new int[0];
}

public void setFont() {
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    for (int i = 0; i<getTextViewsResIds().length; i++){

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(getTextViewsResIds()[i]);
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}

}
```

затем в интересующей вас активити унаследоваться от базовой

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    setFont();
}

@Override
protected int[] getTextViewsResIds() {
    return new int[]{R.id.umivanie_text,R.id.eda_text,R.id.son_text};;
}
}
```

переопределить метод `getTextViewsResIds`, который будет возвращать id ваших TextView (для каждой активити свои, определенные в xml layout) и вызвать в `onCreate` `setFont`

Comment: вам нужно скастить к TextView, (TextView) findViewById(getTextViewsResIds()[i]);

Comment: ,мой косяк,затупил,исправил сразу же,СПАСИБО!

Comment: @upward обновил ответ на более лучший вариант

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2980da5649cd078b22949ba71afc2e15
падает приложение

Comment: setFont вызываете после setContentView?, id указанные в переопределенном методе getTextViewResIds присутствуют в layout той активити, где произошел краш?

Comment: @ Yury Pashkov
public class MainActivity  extends FragmentActivity  //базовый класс
вызываю в onCreate базового класса 
и так же в классах a1,a2,a3
да,id совпадают,проект чистил и перестраивал

Comment: не нужно его в базовом вызывать, только в тех классах, которые наследуются от него

Comment: понял,спасибо.
буду разбираться

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16087956/
дела,все как Вы и сказали..

Comment: создал новый проект дял проверки вашего кода и у меня по прежнему падает приложение на
 textView.setTypeface(typeface);

Comment: @upward у меня все работает, приведите пожалуйста код вашего тестового проекта. Данный краш может произойти только в случае, если в вашем layoute нет такой view  id, который вы указали в переопределенном методе

Comment: если Вас не затруднит, скиньте проект,пожалуйста

Comment: @upward https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_FpaJARaBB2eDRocENsbDNwSHM/view?usp=sharing